A charged body in a rotating frame
In a circular table of radius $R$ rotating with constant angular velocity $\omega$. A charged particle of charge $q_-$ is placed at the edge of the table(at radius $R$ from centre) while a fixed charged particle of charge $q_+$ is at the centre of the table. Assuming that the electrostatic force is greater than the centrifugal force. What is the equation of motion along the radial direction and is it solvable in this scenario? If yes, then can we further determine the equation of trajectory $r(\theta)$.
Edit: I did attempt, and I am getting the equation $m\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2} = \frac{q_+ q_-}{4\pi\epsilon r^2} + m\omega^2 r$, I don't know if this is accurate

Why don't you make an attempat the problem first?

The easiest way to solve this would be to find the trajectory in a non-rotating reference frame (where the problem reduces to the Kepler problem) and then transform the solution into a rotating reference frame.
